# Gradle upgraded but gradle -v still showing the old version - macOS

Tags: java, spring, gradle

On my Mac, I've used brew to upgrade gradle
The upgrade went without any errors
I've lso set GRADLE_HOME to point at the correct gradle version folder and set path to the bin folder in there

But when I run `gradle -v` I still get the old version, and my application complains that it need to work with a later version of gradle

trying to use brew again to upgrade gradle returns a message that I'm on the latest version

I went ahead and downloaded the new gradle version from their website , unzipped it and copied the folder  into `/opt/gradle/`

yet still the problem persists

Any idea how to resove that?

Comment: Try using `type` and/or `which`to figure out which gradle binary is called.

Comment: Thanks @KathrinGeilmann , this has revealed that I've used SDKman in the past to install that particular version for a project, SDKman installs binaries on its own folder. But this made me think that setting GRADLE_HOME doesn't serve any purpose? Please add your comment as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the shell after upgrading setting the gradle home variable?

Comment: I didn't, turns out the old version was installed by SDKman on a different folder, thanks for your help.